# Rails changes schema.rb timestamps to datetimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

This problem seems to happen all the time when working with other developers. We have a table created in a migration like so (backed by postgres):

```
create_table :subscription_events do |t|
  t.integer :subscriber_id
  t.text :source_url
  t.text :params
  t.text :session

  t.timestamps
end
```

Then at seemingly random points in time in the future after running rake db:migrate, Rails wants to update the schema.rb file to use `datetime` instead of `timestamp`, causing an additionally confusing reindentation of the whole create_table calls as well:

```
   create_table "subscription_events", :force => true do |t|
-    t.integer   "subscriber_id"
-    t.text      "source_url"
-    t.text      "params"
-    t.text      "session"
-    t.timestamp "created_at",    :limit => 6, :null => false
-    t.timestamp "updated_at",    :limit => 6, :null => false
+    t.integer  "subscriber_id"
+    t.text     "source_url"
+    t.text     "params"
+    t.text     "session"
+    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
+    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
   end
```

What is causing this?  Should we be checking in this modified file or just reset it every time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should not be causing any 'reindexation', because the `:datetime` and `:timestamp` migration types are both mapped to PostgreSQL's `TIMESTAMP` datatype.

This is likely caused as a result of the inherently unordered `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES` constant which is defined as a standard hash.  When ActiveRecord searches for the first suitable match for 'TIMESTAMP', it may find either `:datetime` or `:timestamp` unpredictably (since both are matches).

In short, don't fuss about it as this shouldn't affect your data or schema in the least.

**UPDATE**

The rails 'datatype' used in the dump is found using the `simplified_type` method which will return `:datetime` for the TIMESTAMP datatype.  More likely, you have upgraded your Rails version where the previous version had a different method for determining the datatype.  Whatever the reason, this shouldn't affect you in any way.

Comment: Great answer!  I think you are right.  The [postgresql_adapter.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L359) maps both to the timestamp datatype, so there's no way to reverse engineer what the original was.  The mappings [haven't changed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L359) since 3.2.6 when our migrations were originally created, so it must be randomly selecting between the two.